# How to fetch one contact's birthday–swift iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, contacts

I am relatively new to swift and iOS, and I am having some trouble integrating with Contacts. I have used apple's resources (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html), but I can not figure out how to fetch the birthday of a single contact. I want to take the name a user types in and output the matching contact's birthday to a label. I am using `let contacts = try store.unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingName("\(fullnamefield.text!) \(lastnamefield.text!) \(suffixfield.text!)"), keysToFetch:[CNContactBirthdayKey])`, but this results in an array that I just can not make sense of.

Your help in **finding a specific contact's birthday** in swift with the new Contacts Framework would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The array is of type `[CNContact]`, I believe. You'll need to loop through it and retrieve the `birthday` property, but if you're only finding one contact you can get the first item out of the array and get it's birthday:

```
let store = CNContactStore()

//This line retrieves all contacts for the current name and gets the birthday and name properties
let contacts:[CNContact] = try store.unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingName("\(fullnamefield.text!) \(lastnamefield.text!) \(suffixfield.text!)"), keysToFetch:[CNContactBirthdayKey, CNContactGivenNameKey])

//Get the first contact in the array of contacts (since you're only looking for 1 you don't need to loop through the contacts)
let contact = contacts[0]

//Check if the birthday field is set
if let bday = contact.birthday?.date as NSDate! {
    //Use the NSDateFormatter to convert their birthday (an NSDate) to a String
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") // You must set the time zone from your default time zone to UTC +0, which is what birthdays in Contacts are set to.
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy" //Set the format of the date converter
    let stringDate = formatter.stringFromDate(contact.birthday!.date!)

    //Their birthday as a String:
    print(stringDate)
}
```

Comment: I tried this and (thanks!) but it outputs the day before someone's birthday. I tried it on Kate Bell, a default contact in the simulator (her birthday is January 20th, 1978) and it outputted 19/1/1978. Any ideas?

Comment: never mind! I just needed to set the timezone as suggested here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/32046811/5700898). I've amended your answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: @GabrielJones Please don't ask users for upvotes.  You can remind them to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if they are new, but judging from John Ramos' profile they have asked questions and accepted answers in the past, and know how to do so.

Comment: @JAL Ok, ok, he was just being helpful! He saved me many hours of fruitless work, so I think he deserved that upvote.

Comment: @JohnRamos I'm glad he helped!  And you are most welcome to vote and accept answers on your own merits, but users should not be asking for upvotes or accepts.

Comment: @Jal Understood. Thanks.