# How to add characters into dateFormatter

Tags: swift, date

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17542713/5175709) answer, but it doesn't work for me.

I want to format my time as:

> "2017-09-11**T**11:45:00-04:00"

I'm doing:

```
let xFormatter = DateFormatter()
xFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss-04:00"
print(xFormatter.string(from: date))
```

I need a **T** between the date and time. however if I add that, my format turns into something like:

> 2017-09-11

(The -4:00 at the end is a timeoffset which I hardcode...)

Comment: *"I followed this answer"* - no you didn't. You forgot the quotes.

Comment: @rmaddy the quotes are on the `dd`, `yyyy`, `MMMM`. I don't see it on the strings themselves. Or am I not understanding that answer properly?

Comment: Read the words of the answer, don't just look at the code (which you are reading incorrectly).

Comment: yeah you're' right. the 'MMMM' made it confusing... I was initially trying: 'yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'-04:00 and then got lost. I actually first though the formatting there is confusing and should be changed. I still agree it's confusing, but **it's necessary**. That is the spaces are required to have the format as the OP intended...First time I'm actually doing anything with dates :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add single quotes

```
xFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-04:00"
```

From the documentation:

> ... This includes the need to enclose ASCII letters in single quotes if they are intended to represent literal text.

Source: [Unicode.org: Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

**Edit:**

Be aware that the time zone is just an amendment to the string, it's not considered by the date formatter.

To consider the time zone you have to set the `timeZone` of the formatter

```
xFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: -14400)
```

In iOS 10.0+ and macOS 10.12+ there is a more convenient way to create an ISO8601 string

```
let isoFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
isoFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: -14400)
isoFormatter.formatOptions = .withInternetDateTime
print(isoFormatter.string(from: Date()))
```

Comment: psssh. Thanks. I know this works. Just _curious_ do you know if there is any documentation on that?

Comment: @Honey Apple mentions the Unicode Technical Standard they follow here: [Apple Data Formatting Guide: Date Formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1). They don't mention if they have upgraded from version tr35-31 but I'd assume they have given that was from iOS 7 and we're up to iOS 10.